# Changing In-App Purchase name synchronously with new app version

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Is it possible to change In-App purchase name synchronously with new app version? I've made changes to my In-App purchase and I want it's new display name to appear on iTunes at the same moment when the new app version appears on iTunes. I couldn't find it out from iTunes Connect developer guide. When I change In-App Purchase display name on iTunes Connect it gets Waiting For Review status but I can see now way to tie this with my new app version release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different kind of review processes. If you upload your app, you should be able to update the `In-App-Purchase` `Display Name` without the review process.

If your app is already uploaded and you are updating the app to a higher version, it is independent from the changed `Display Name` of you `In-App-Purchase`. I'm still looking for the duration of the `Display Name`. Will be updating my post if I can find something.

Here are some information about `In-App-Purchases` [inside the Apple Documentation](http://bit.ly/stackInAppPurchase)

Comment: did you find any update on this? can we update display name in 2nd scenario??